# How to roll 3 random strings out an array and check them

Tags: python, arrays, random

I am a student programmer at college and I've only recently started coding in my own time. I have some basic knowledge on how to program but arrays are out of my knowledge and I am trying to learn them. I got challenged to make a fruit roll gambling machine. I need to roll 3 strings out of a possible 6 and check for certain conditions.

I have figured out how to take 3 of those out and print them but I need to check for winners etc. For 3 bells you win the jackpot, for 2 dupes + another you win a regular prize, if you roll the skull you get a deduction.

I think I can figure out how to check which ones are rolled by just using if and else if statements (not sure if it works) but it will be a lot of else if's to make sure each and every combination is considered for.

Is there a quicker way to check for duplicates? Or is just using lots of elif statements the only way to do it. I can elaborate further if required.

I've pasted the full code below, forgive me if its not well written I'm still only like beginner level, I was also told to try use functions which is why there is so many. My main problem is as I described before but any other tips for the entirety of the code will be well appreciated too. Thanks in advance.

```
import random
fruit = ["Cherry", "Bell", "Lemon", "Star", "Orange", "Skull"]


def fruit_machine():
  credits = 10
  credit = True
  while credits > 0:
    turn = str(input("Would you like to roll for 20p? Y/N: "))
    if turn.lower() == "y":
      credits = credits - 2
      credits_print(credits)
    elif turn.lower() == "n":
      print("You have chosen not to roll.")
      credit = False
    else:
      print("Please enter a valid option.")
  return credits
  return credit


def credits_print(credits):
  print("You have", credits, "credits remaining")
  fruit_roll()
  if credits == 0:
    print("--------------------------------------\nYou have no more credits remaining")
    end()
    
  

def fruit_roll(credits):
  roll = random.choices(fruit, k = 3)
  if roll == ["Bell, Bell, Bell"]:
    print("Jackpot!!!\n+5 credits")
    credits = credits + 5
  
  

def end():
  print(" ")




fruit_machine()
```

I had made the end() as I couldn't figure out how to stop it looping back to the fruit_machine function after reaching 0 credits, it would just go back and go into negatives.

Comment: If `len(set(roll)) == 2`, then there was a pair, plus another fruit.

Comment: You could also use `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more streamlined ways to check for duplicates and other conditions in a list rather than using a bunch of if elif statements. The logic is going to change based on the requirements and combinations of roll results. For example, is it just 3 Bells that hit the jackpot or is it 3 of any roll except skull?

An example fruit_roll function based on the requirements in your question would be something like this:

```
def fruit_roll(credits):
 roll = random.choices(fruit, k=3)
 print("Rolled: ", roll)
 if roll.count("Bell") == 3:
    print("Jackpot!!! +5 credits")
    credits += 5
 elif any(roll.count(f) == 2 for f in fruit) and "Skull" not in roll:
    print("Regular prize! +2 credits")
    credits += 2
 if "Skull" in roll:
    print("Skull rolled! -1 credit")
    credits -= 1
 return credits
```

There were some other issues with your code that I found when going through it.

1. In fruit_roll() you are comparing roll to a string ("Bell, Bell, Bell" in your code). This won't work because roll is a list and not a string.
2. In fruit_machine() you call fruit_roll() without passing in the credits variable.
3. You have two return statements for fruit_machine(). The second return statement will never run since the first return statement will cause the function to exit.

The tweaked code with the roll evaluation logic is below.

```
import random

fruit = ["Cherry", "Bell", "Lemon", "Star", "Orange", "Skull"]

def fruit_machine():
    credits = 10
    while credits > 0:
        turn = str(input("Would you like to roll for 20p? Y/N: "))
        if turn.lower() == "y":
            credits -= 2  # Deduct 20p
            credits = fruit_roll(credits)  # Roll fruits and update credits
            credits_print(credits)
        elif turn.lower() == "n":
            print("You have chosen not to roll.")
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter a valid option.")
    print("--------------------------------------\nYou have no more credits remaining")
    end()

def credits_print(credits):
    print("You have", credits, "credits remaining")

def fruit_roll(credits):
    roll = random.choices(fruit, k=3)
    print("Rolled: ", roll)
    if roll.count("Bell") == 3:
        print("Jackpot!!! +5 credits")
        credits += 5
    elif any(roll.count(f) == 2 for f in fruit) and "Skull" not in roll:
        print("Regular prize! +2 credits")
        credits += 2
    if "Skull" in roll:
        print("Skull rolled! -1 credit")
        credits -= 1
    return credits

def end():
    print("Game Over.")

fruit_machine()
```

Comment: I think I understand most of the tweaked code you have posted but I am not quite sure on this part:
    elif any(roll.count(f) == 2 for f in fruit) and "Skull" not in roll:
what does the (f) do?? same with the "for f in fruit"
Same with the "any" function on the first elif statement you used in the fruit_roll

Comment: @caleb, the f is a variable. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47789/6394617).